# AngularJS debugging techniques

Tags: angularjs, javascript-debugger

the story:

i solved a problem about angularjs searching on google and i found the solution.
the problem has started from a specific version of angularjs, when the angular team has removed a module from the core of the library and now you have to explicitly indicate if you use it.
the module i'm speaking about is "ngRoute"

before:

```
<script src="angular.js"></script>
...
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['someOtherModule']);
```

after

```
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="angular-route.js"></script>
...
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'someOtherModule']);
...
```

this is the solution
(the error consisted simply that the modul was not loaded)

my question is:

1. how can i debug angularjs (for didactic purpose) to understand
   that module wasn't load?
2. what tool do i need to debug? (if i
   need it)
3. below the message error that the problem caused (what
   does it suggest to me? what is the "key" indication to find the
   problem?)
4. any suggestion to debug this particular problem? 
   does "a stack trace" exist to follow what angularjs does internally
   step-by-step?

the error message:

```
Eccezione non gestita alla riga 3845, colonna 9 in http://localhost:12153/Scripts/angular.js

0x800a139e - Errore di run-time di JavaScript: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module TodoApp due to:

Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngRoute due to:

Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngRoute' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.18/$injector/nomod?p0=ngRoute

   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:12153/Scripts/angular.js:1643:11)

   at ensure (http://localhost:12153/Scripts/angular.js:1567:5)

   at module (http://localhost:12153/Scripts/angular.js:1641:7)

   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:12153/Scripts/angular.js:3817:11)

   at forEach (http://localhost:12153/Scripts/angular.js:320:7)

   at loadModules (http://localhost:12153/Scripts/angular.js:3811:5)

   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:12153/Scripts/angular.js:3818:11)

   at forEach (http://localhost:12153/Scripts/angular.js:320:7)

   at loadModules (http://localhost:12153/Scripts/angular.js:3811:5)

   at createInjector (http://localhost:12153/Scripts/angular.js:3751:3)

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.18/$injector/modulerr?p0=ngRoute&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20Module%20'ngRoute'%20is%20not%20available!%20You%20either%20misspelled%20the%20module%20name%20or%20forgot%20to%20load%20it.%20If%20registering%20a%20module%20ensure%20that%20you%20specify%20the%20dependencies%20as%20the%20second%20argument.%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.18%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DngRoute%0A%20%20%20at%20Anonymous%20function%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12153%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A1643%3A11)%0A%20%20%20at%20ensure%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12153%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A1567%3A5)%0A%20%20%20at%20module%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12153%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A1641%3A7)%0A%20%20%20at%20Anonymous%20function%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12153%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A3817%3A11)%0A%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12153%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A320%3A7)%0A%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12153%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A3811%3A5)%0A%20%20%20at%20Anonymous%20function%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12153%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A3818%3A11)%0A%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12153%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A320%3A7)%0A%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12153%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A3811%3A5)%0A%20%20%20at%20createInjector%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12153%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A3751%3A3)

   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:12153/Scripts/angular.js:3845:9)

   at forEach (http://localhost:12153/Scripts/angular.js:320:7)

   at loadModules (http://localhost:12153/Scripts/angular.js:3811:5)

   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:12153/Scripts/angular.js:3818:11)

   at forEach (http://localhost:12153/Scripts/angular.js:320:7)

   at loadModules (http://localhost:12153/Scripts/angular.js:3811:5)

   at createInjector (http://localhost:12153/Scripts/angular.js:3751:3)

   at doBootstrap (http://localhost:12153/Scripts/angular.js:1410:5)

   at bootstrap (http://localhost:12153/Scripts/angular.js:1425:5)

   at angularInit (http://localhost:12153/Scripts/angular.js:1338:5)

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.18/$injector/modulerr?p0=TodoApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20Failed%20to%20instantiate%20module%20ngRoute%20due%20to%3A%0AError%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20Module%20'ngRoute'%20is%20not%20available!%20You%20either%20misspelled%20the%20module%20name%20or%20forgot%20to%20load%20it.%20If%20registering%20a%20module%20ensure%20that%20you%20specify%20the%20dependencies%20as%20the%20second%20argument.%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.18%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DngRoute%0A%20%20%20at%20Anonymous%20function%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12153%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A1643%3A11)%0A%20%20%20at%20ensure%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12153%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A1567%3A5)%0A%20%20%20at%20module%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12153%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A1641%3A7)%0A%20%20%20at%20Anonymous%20function%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12153%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A3817%3A11)%0A%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12153%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A320%3A7)%0A%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12153%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A3811%3A5)%0A%20%20%20at%20Anonymous%20function%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12153%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A3818%3A11)%0A%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12153%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A320%3A7)%0A%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12153%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A3811%3A5)%0A%20%20%20at%20createInjector%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12153%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A3751%3A3)%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.18%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DngRoute%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520Module%2520'ngRoute'%2520is%2520not%2520available!%2520You%2520either%2520misspelled%2520the%2520module%2520name%2520or%2520forgot%2520to%2520load%2520it.%2520If%2520registering%2520a%2520module%2520ensure%2520that%2520you%2520specify%2520the%2520dependencies%2520as%2520the%2520second%2520argument.%250Ahttp%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.2.18%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DngRoute%250A%2520%2520%2520at%2520Anonymous%2520function%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A12153%252FScripts%252Fangular.js%253A1643%253A11)%250A%2520%2520%2520at%2520ensure%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A12153%252FScripts%252Fangular.js%253A1567%253A5)%250A%2520%2520%2520at%2520module%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A12153%252FScripts%252Fangular.js%253A1641%253A7)%250A%2520%2520%2520at%2520Anonymous%2520function%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A12153%252FScripts%252Fangular.js%253A3817%253A11)%250A%2520%2520%2520at%2520forEach%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A12153%252FScripts%252Fangular.js%253A320%253A7)%250A%2520%2520%2520at%2520loadModules%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A12153%252FScripts%252Fangular.js%253A3811%253A5)%250A%2520%2520%2520at%2520Anonymous%2520function%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A12153%252FScripts%252Fangular.js%253A3818%253A11)%250A%2520%2520%2520at%2520forEach%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A12153%252FScripts%252Fangular.js%253A320%253A7)%250A%2520%2520%2520at%2520loadModules%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A12153%252FScripts%252Fangular.js%253A3811%253A5)%250A%2520%2520%2520at%2520createInjector%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A12153%252FScripts%252Fangular.js%253A3751%253A3)%0A%20%20%20at%20Anonymous%20function%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12153%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A3845%3A9)%0A%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12153%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A320%3A7)%0A%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12153%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A3811%3A5)%0A%20%20%20at%20Anonymous%20function%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12153%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A3818%3A11)%0A%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12153%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A320%3A7)%0A%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12153%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A3811%3A5)%0A%20%20%20at%20createInjector%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12153%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A3751%3A3)%0A%20%20%20at%20doBootstrap%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12153%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A1410%3A5)%0A%20%20%20at%20bootstrap%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12153%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A1425%3A5)%0A%20%20%20at%20angularInit%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12153%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A1338%3A5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the google chrome extension [Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/details). I think it will satisfy some of your requirements. It Extends the Developer Tools, adding tools for debugging and profiling AngularJS applications.

[Here is the link to the blog post and demo video:](http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2012/07/introducing-angularjs-batarang.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. Angularjs provide error message and you just posted it

   Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate **module** **ngRoute** due to:

   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngRoute' is not available! You either **misspelled the module name or forgot to load it**. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
2. For debugging angular there is [AngularJS Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) plugin. It is more for debugging scope values;
3. Here is the key to solve you problem: **Module 'ngRoute' is not available!**
4. Again I think angular error log is pretty verbose to make you help find right way to solve the problem

Also documentation is very helpful, here [ngRoute installation instruction](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute)